# Can a tablet be slaved to a laptop to act as a wireless usb?

Tags: mobile-robot

I have built an InMoov Robot. The tablet I got for his controller is too slow. I am currently using a laptop to control him across a usb cable. I want to get rid of the usb cable.

I was thinking of using the embedded tablet as one end of the link (slave), and the laptop as the other. That should give me the speed of the laptop without the usb Cable.

Can this be done?  How?

Comment: Have you solved this question yet? I, for one, would like to see how you solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to program the tablet to do this, but you might have to create your own app to do this.

If you're not using the tablet for anything else, it might be easier to use a raspberry pi zero-w to do this. In a Linux environment it is easy to program servers like this in the language of your choice. I'd use rust, but Python, C/C++, Go, or Java will do the job also. And I'm sure that I've only scratched the surface (pun fully intended). There are multiple serial libraries, depending on the language you finally choose.